# SQL order groups of data

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here I have a data sample:

| Title | Size | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 3 | 14 |
| First | 5 | 3 |
| Second | 2 | 5 |
| First | 2 | 10 |
| Third | 3 | 10 |
| Second | 3 | 4 |
| Third | 2 | 9 |
| Third | 5 | 11 |
| Second | 5 | 4 |

Now I want to sort the data with following rules:

Put the records with same title together: First followed by First, Second followed by Second.

Then for each group, order them by size;

For groups, order them in the sum of count of each group, like: sum of First is 14+3+10=27, Second is 5+4+4=13, Third is 10+9+11=30.

The result I want:

| Title | Size | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Second | 2 | 5 |
| Second | 3 | 4 |
| Second | 5 | 4 |
| First | 2 | 10 |
| First | 3 | 14 |
| First | 5 | 3 |
| Third | 2 | 9 |
| Third | 3 | 10 |
| Third | 5 | 11 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an easy sort once you get the total "Count" per Title.
A `SUM OVER` can be used for that.

```
SELECT
  q.title AS "Title"
, q.size AS "Size"
, q.count AS "Count"
FROM
(
   SELECT t.title, t.size, t.count
   , SUM(t.count) OVER (PARTITION BY t.title) AS TotalCount
   FROM yourtable t
) q
ORDER BY q.TotalCount, q.title, q.size
```

| Title | Size | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Second | 2 | 5 |
| Second | 3 | 4 |
| Second | 5 | 4 |
| First | 2 | 10 |
| First | 3 | 14 |
| First | 5 | 3 |
| Third | 2 | 9 |
| Third | 3 | 10 |
| Third | 5 | 11 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fd043781a97f0514b6a1a2b5824e8b0e)*

Comment: Thanks! I guess you don't need to order by q.title at the end.

Comment: You do have to also order by title. For when 2 titles have the same total amount.  Actually, you could still add Count as last tie-breaker to the sort. Would just be as fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` the results of the group count sums back onto the main table, using the sums in the `order by` clause:

```
select t.* from tbl t join 
       (select t1.title, sum(t1.cnt) s from tbl t1 group by t1.title) t2 
on t.title = t2.title order by t2.s, t.title, t.size;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is by using [**WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions**)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-with.html)

```
with ct
as (
    select title
        ,size
        ,count
        ,sum(count) over (partition by title) sm
    from tbl
    )
select title
      ,size
      ,count
from ct
order by ct.sm,2;
```